# How to Make One Cell equal different cell values on multiple sheets and locations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working in Excel 2010, and my question is how do I make a cell (say on one sheet to equal a specific value placed on another sheet). I thought the following formula would do it but it doesn't work.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Name,$A2)=1,VLOOKUP($A2,Name,2,FALSE),''))
```

Comment: Some clarification of your problem would help understand your issue. As in what criteria are you using to know where to get the value from the other sheet? Why should it take such value and not another value? And your formula has unbalanced parentheses right now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you simply want one cell to represent the value of another cell from another sheet?  If so, the formula will look like this:  `=[name of sheet]![cell reference]` EG:  `=sheet2!A1`

If used in cell A1 on sheet 1, this would put the value of cell A1 from sheet2 into A1 of sheet 1.

If you modify your question so that you reference the actual sheets & cells you're interested in, I can help you with the formula.

You can easily facilitate this by writing your formula in the bar, then when you need to reference a cell on a different sheet, simply navigate to the sheet & cell to insert it's address into the formula, then carry on with your formula if necessary.